# Azure DocumentDB suddenly failing to create client

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Azure DocumentDB is failing on `new DocumentClient(URI, Key, ConnectionPolicy)` on my production and dev .Net applications. It's been running smoothly for 4 months.

[image: VS debug]

I've tested setting up new DB's and deploying the Azure Sample apps, but same error today. 
Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: We are investigating.

Comment: What's the DocumentDB .NET SDK version you are using? Is "Key" in your example, a master key token or a resource key token?

Comment: I assume that this is only in the debugger Watch window that is showing this error. Your application is running fine right? Please confirm that your application is running fine and not throwing an exception at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Rajesh
It's been running on Microsoft Azure DocumentDB Client 1.11.1. Initially tried updating to 1.13.1, but still same error.

I'm using the primary key for DocumentDB from the portal (also tried secondary). I actually got the same error after I deleted the DB resource in the picture above.

Yes, I spotted the error only through the debugger. The application is running fine. 
After n attempts the Dev app(Azure web app) started working by it self, no fix/change implemented. Still not working on Prod or local testing etc.

Comment: Sidenote: Had friends set up test sample apps at that time on different subscriptions aswell. They also produced the same error.